# React overwrite component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I'm trying to do the following, currently I have 3 components:

Parent.js:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  applyFilters = () => {console.log("applying original filters")}

  setApplyFilters = (callback) => {
    this.applyFilters = () => callback();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Filters applyFilters={this.applyFilters} />
        <Screen1 setApplyFilters={this.setApplyFilters} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Filters.js:

```
class Filters extends Component {
  onButtonPress = () => {
    this.props.applyFilters(),
  }

  render(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Screen1.js:

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
  applyFilter = () => {
    console.log("Applying filters using the callback function in Screen1");
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.setApplyFilters(() => this.applyFilters());
  }

  render(){
    ...
  }
}
```

I have a Filters component that is common to all the screens. I have multiple screens of the type Screen1.

I want to on `componentDidMount` of the current screen pass the `applyFilter` function as a callback to the parent, and from the parent pass the `applyFilter` as a prop to the Filter component. When the `onButtonPressed` handler of the filter is called, it should execute the `applyFilter` callback for the mounted screen.

But for some reason it just prints to the console "applying original filters" which is the original string, as if the function is not being overwritten with the callback from the screen.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: I think you need to rerender the `Parent` component so that the new `applyFilters` method can be passed to `Filter`

Comment: This seems like you are trying to solve a problem with a non-react solution. Likely there is a better way to solve your original problem that is more inline with idiomatic react. What is the result you want here? I mean what do you want the app to do, not in terms of the code, but in terms of the flow of the app?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What I'm trying to do is, the app has a filter component with several combo boxes which is the same component for all the "screen" componentes that we have below. So if I change between screens the Filter component shouldn't rerender. The filter component has a button to apply the selected filters to the current screen data. Hope I'm making myself clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this.applyFilters` is resolved early during the render process to `() => {console.log("applying original filters")}`

```
<Filters applyFilters={this.applyFilters} />
```

In this scenario you only care for its value at the time that the function it references is invoked, so you want to set it lazily.

```
<Filters applyFilters={() => this.applyFilters()} />
```

This way when `applyFilters` invoked in `Filters` component, the value that is referenced in `this.applyFilters` is resolved and then invoked.

Comment: There is a difference in the rendering of both. The former binds early to component method, the later one does it later at the time that `props.applyFilters` is invoked in the `Filters` component.

Comment: You are totally right. I'm accepting your solution due to not needing to rerender the component as on marzelin's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After changing `applyFilters` on the parent, rerender it i.e. with `forceUpdate` to make `Filter` component receive the changed function.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  applyFilters = () => {console.log("applying original filters")}

  setApplyFilters = (callback) => {
    this.applyFilters = () => callback();
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Filters applyFilters={this.applyFilters} />
        <Screen1 setApplyFilters={this.setApplyFilters} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```